# Get total values in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use "totalsForAllResults" method in google apps script to push out total values for each metrics.
I printed out result of each metrics by each dimension to a spreadsheet. And I'd like to see the total values at the end of the row. I tried many times but cat't get it work. I'll be happy if anybody give me advice.

The problem is the last paragraph. This code worked for get analytics data but "totalsForAllResults"  doesn't work.

```
var results = ChannelReportPC(firstProfile); 
  　outputToSpreadsheet(results);

function ChannelReportPC(firstProfile) { 

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = electiveStartDate('SD');  
  var endDate = electiveEndDate('ED');     

  var optArgs = { 
    'dimensions': 'ga:medium',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'sort': '-ga:sessions',      
    'segment': 'sessions::condition::ga:deviceCategory==desktop,ga:deviceCategory==tablet',  // Process desktop or tablet traffic.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '20'
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
    'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactionsPerSession', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
     optArgs
     );

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("media");

}

function outputToSpreadsheet(results) {

  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()


  // Print the headers.
  var headerNames = [];
  for (var i = 0, header; header = results.getColumnHeaders()[i]; ++i) {
    headerNames.push(header.getName());
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, headerNames.length)
      .setValues([headerNames])
      .setBackground('#eeeeee');


  // Print the rows of data.
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
      .setValues(results.getRows());    


  sheet.getRange(getRows().length+1, 2, 1, headerNames.length)
  .setValues(results.totalsForAllResults);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the code in such a format that it stood alone, and demonstrated the problem in as few lines as possible. Currently I can only guess what might be passed into this function as a 'result'.

Comment: The problem is last paragraph contains "results.totalsForAllResults". The code worked except that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your `results.totalForAllresults` contains array of values. If it is, try to convert it into array of array. Try to follow these steps for your code,

```
  data = [];
  data.push(results.totalsForAllResults);
  sheet.getRange(getRows().length+1, 2, 1, headerNames.length).setValues(data);
```